# How can I measure the width (diameter) of a hair using OpenCV?

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I am trying to quantify the width (in pixels) of hair using OpenCV.

Right now, I use a segmentation to binarize the image, then an idea I had is to generate lines over the image, and then using an AND gate, get the line widths, use FindContours to get the contours, then use ContourArea to calculate the area of each contour, sum them, and finally calculate the pixelWidth using the square root of the area divided by the number of contours:

This is the segmented and binarized crop of hair:

[image: Binarized hair]

Then, this is the line mask I will apply to the previous image:

[image: Line masks]

And finally, this is the result of the AND gate between both images:

[image: Final masks]

Then, the code I am using to calculate the pixel width, given the contours of the previous image:

```
for (int i=0; i < blobs.Size; i++) // Blobs is the result of FindContours
  area += CvInvoke.ContourArea(blobs[i]);
pixelWidth += Math.Sqrt(area / blobs.Size);

return (int)Math.Ceiling(pixelWidth);
```

The result I am obtaining here, is 5 pixels width, whereas the real pixel width I can check with GIMP is about 6-8 (depending of the section).

I tested this method with several hairs, and in most ocassions the measure is wrong for about 1 pixel, in others the measure is correct, and in other like the shown, it fails for various pixels.

Do you know any way to face this problem better?

Comment: [mre] please. that implies input data.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz hello, you can take the first image as input image. About the code, just performed AND operation between mask and input data, and then a FindContours. The rest of the code is the shown in the post. Let me know if further clarification is needed.

Comment: that's very little data. and it appears resampled. screenshot? screenshots aren't data. -- I'd recommend _not_ having a line mask at all. simply take pixel columns at various positions, then work with those 1D signals (find first and last nonzero index). -- if you want to keep using such a mask anyway, don't look for contours. get connected components *with stats*. that'll give you the bounding box for each component, fairly directly.

Comment: And then take an average of width? Could be a good approach. Using the mask, could give in some cases wrong results due to masking a section that has not been fully segmented due to color/luminance variations. I'll try without a mask and check. In this time I've improved the masking method and now is somehow precise. It can determine the width in most of the cases with a good precision, but still fails in some cases. Ty for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm
Step1: Detect contour points using FindContours().
Step2: Find bounding rectangle by using BoundingRect() and the detected contour points.
Step3: The width of the rectangle is the desired output.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the comment. I've tested this method before, but was not giving good results because when the input is a large hair could be in a non straight form, giving a much wider output. This method performs fine when the input image is as the image shown. And even in the image shown you can observe that a bounding rectangle would not fit correctly to the hair.